# How to set some dropout when training a neural network using MxNet?

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

When training a Deep Convolutional Neural Network using MxNet, what is the simplest way to turn on some amount of dropout in order to reduce overfitting? Is there a way to add a dropout rate without manually implementing dropout in the network architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set the dropout rate.
The dropout layer API is here: https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/symbol/symbol.html?highlight=dropout#mxnet.symbol.Dropout

Where **p** is the dropout rate.

Comment: Thanks George for the answer. I found that API while searching too. However it is not clear to me how we are supposed to use it if we have an implementation of a network like Resnet or InceptionV3. Could you add an example?

Comment: It is just like adding any other layer to the network:

`conv1 = mx.sym.Convolution(data=act1, num_filter=int(num_filter*0.25), kernel=(1,1)...)

dropout1 = symbol.Dropout(conv1, p = 0.2)`